# Why does my TuringMachine rule fail to display correctly using RulePlot?

Tags: plotting, cellular-automata

Why does the following work

```
rules={
{1,2}->{1,2,1},
{1,1}->{1,1,1},
{1,0}->{2,0,-1},
{2,1}->{3,2,0},
{2,2}->{2,1,-1},
{2,0}->{3,2,0},
{3,1}->{3,1,0},
{3,2}->{3,2,0},
{3,0}->{3,0,0}
};
RulePlot[TuringMachine[rules],turingStyle]
```

while this fails

```
rules={
{1,2}->{1,2,1},
{1,1}->{1,1,1},
{1,0}->{2,0,-1},
{2,1}->{3,2,0},
{2,2}->{2,1,-1},
{2,0}->{3,2,0},
{3,1}->{3,1,0},
{3,2}->{3,2,0},
{3,0}->{3,0,2}
};
RulePlot[TuringMachine[rules],turingStyle]
```

Both `rules` seem to conform to the documentation for a `TuringMachine` rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look into the definition of `RulePlot` for `TuringMachine`, it checks whether the rule is valid with `ValidTuringMachineRulesQ`:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
PrintDefinitions[NKSSpecialFunctions`RulePlot`Dump`ValidTuringMachineRulesQ]
```

Unfortunately it only expects offsets of no more than 1 `... {_Integer, _Integer, -1 | 0 | 1} ...`

If you patch this function to accept any offset, your rule would look like
[image]

which obviously requires more internal tweaking of `RulePlot`.

Comment: And `ValidTuringMachineQ` is applying a definition of “valid” that is different from the one used by `TuringMachine`?

Comment: @orome `TuringMachine` doesn't need to check that much, it just computes an evolution. You can patch it with `PrintDefinitions`, the plot wouldn't look so good by default though. I guess the developers didn't expect for more generic rules to work.